# Dell Perc 6/e Firmware

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

Working on a PowerEdge R210 with an attached MD1000 Powervault, i was just doing some basic upkeep on it when i noticed in the logs it was complaining about the Perc 6/e having incompatible firmware.  The array is working, but its spamming the logs about the storage controller firmware.

So i went over to Dell and the newest firmware listed on their site for the Perc 6/e is version 6.3.3-0002, A-00..

When i log into the Dell OpenManage it shows me that the current firmware of the Perc 6/e is version 9.0.1-0037, so i ran the firmware installation package from Dell just to see what it would say, yes the data is backed up and not a lot on it so not a major concern if something bad happens, it says the firmware installed is already newer then the installation package, but according to Dell 6.3.3-0002 A-00 is the newest.

Any ideas?  Did someone force the wrong firmware on this Perc 6/e before i came along?  If so is there anyway to revert it to the latest firmware from Dell?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that version number - it sounds like someone may have flashed that card with LSI firmware (they're the OEM for the card)

You may try updating it with the latest firmware from LSI:
http://docs.avagotech.com/docs/12350259

I suspect their tools would block you from flashing this version due to the non-OEM ID on the card though, since it's Dell branded.

You may simply be stuck having to replace the card at this point, unless LSI's CLI tools have an option to "force" a firmware flash.

Comment: Hmm, i will try the firmware from LSI, if that doesn't work i might just ignore it. System works fine otherwise, Dell's Open Manage is just having a hissy fit about it.

Comment: Have you noticed what type of card brand/model is listed during the boot process,when the "press Ctrl + R" prompt is shown? If it shows as a Dell PERC, not LSI, and the same is shown in the PERC BIOS (when you do press Ctrl + R), then you may actually have a refurbished card that was shipped as a replacement, running debug firmware that was never replaced during the rework process.

Comment: No i havent really paid attention to it during boot, i will have to check that next time i reboot this server.  I did push the latest LSI firmware version 11 and it took it no problems or complaints.  I have had the cover off this one to add some RAM and the card is Dell branded, Dell barcode label, Dell branded Battery, etc.